# Django jquery ajax 403 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, json

I am trying to get ajax to work, but I keep getting a 403 error. I am quite new to jquery.

The following is my code

```
    $('#prod_search_button').click(function(){
    if ($('#inv_prod_list').length) {
        //insert a new record
    }
    else
    {
        //create the #inv_prod_list table and insert first record
        var inv_table= '<table id="inv_prod_list" style="border: 2px solid #dddddd;"></table>';

        // create query object
        var prod_query = {
            query: jQuery.trim($('#id_prod_query').val())
        };

        // convert object to JSON data
        var jsonQuery = JSON.stringify(prod_query);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/company/product/item_search.json/',
            data: jsonQuery,

             success: function(jsonData){
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
                    $('#inv_prod_wrap').html(inv_table);

                    var new_record = 'this is html for new row'

                    $('#inv_prod_list tr:last').after(new_record);



                    //off rows alt color
                   }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Use Firebug (a Firefox extension) (or another Javascript console) to see what the reason behind the 403 is. You'll see the Django error page (with the helpful hint about the CSRF token) then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30210391/940098

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you [don't pass CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem, thanks! All I had to do was copy that piece of code from the official docs into a js file and include it in my html.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the CSRF by adding the following annotation before your method definition.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def Method():
```

Answer (score 2):

just copy that piece of code from [the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) into a js file and include it in your html

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue =   decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the HTTP/1.1 Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). "403" is the status code "Forbidden". This is an error being thrown on the server side of your `$.ajax` request, not the client side (i.e. your code is making a request, but the response from the server is an error message).

The document indicates servers should respond with that error only in specific situations:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

Typically, an error of this sort means that whatever user you're logged in as does not have access to the URL you are requesting. Often, this indicates that the only error in your code is the URL you are making the request to or the ordering of a sequence of calls (e.g. you are trying to request data before logging in). Less commonly, some web servers and web applications are configured to respond with 403 error codes instead of 404 (not found) error codes for all "invalid" requests to avoid leaking information about what files do/don't exist on the server.

Comment: that is not the problem. I have tried removing all user validation requirements and it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and figured I'd post what was going on. I had the `{% CSRF_TOKEN %}` in a cached paged and it was caching what it put there. So for some users it was valid and some it wasn't depending on the cache! It was a nightmare to track down even though it should have been obvious... So check your caching.

Answer (score 0):

Can also check if csrf middleware is enabled in settings.py and disable it. Look for `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`.

Comment: One should not disable `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` without fully understanding the consequences.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/

Answer (score 0):

For request type `POST`, just add a reference to csrf_token:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ...,
        data: ...,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',    // Added csrf_token
         success: function(jsonData){
            // ...
         },
    });
```

Comment: It's not good practice to put template variables directly into JS code, a better method would be to put `{% csrf_token %}` in the form and call it with `document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value`