# attempting to alter data via POST and ajax in django not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I want to be able to click a button that will change data using ajax (jquery). Here is what I am doing now:

html/js:

```
<button onclick="alterData('some sort of data')">click me!</button>

function alterData(someInput){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/home/alter/',
        data: {someInput: someInput},
    });
}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...

   url(r'^alter/',views.alter),

   ...
]
```

views.py:

```
def alter(request):
   print request.POST['someInput']
```

I receive a red runserver print when clicking the button:

```
"POST /home/alter/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2274
```

changing up the above to be GET works, it's just that POST doesn't

Comment: did you check this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646781/django-jquery-ajax-403-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [this documentation from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax), I guess you are missing the CSRF Token in your POST data.

Comment: Gocht and HassenPy directed me to what I was looking for. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request  was also very helpful